# Heroku деплой приложения

Tags: python, django, heroku

Пытаюсь развернуть приложение на Heroku. По сути push команда запускает приложение (как я понял) но дает ошибку code=H14
Нагуглил решение с помощью `heroku ps:scale web=1` При выполнении команды сталкиваюсь с новой сложностью

```
▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

`Судя по всему, нужен некий Procfile. Не совсем понял, что это и как его получить

[image: Скриншот Django проекта]

Answer (score 0):

В этом файле(Procfile) вы должны указать то что будет запускаться

Наведу пример:
[image: Запуск бота на Heroku]

Через етот файл у меня запускаеться бот.

Пишете так же как на фото только вместо Bot.py вы должны написать тот файл через который будет запускаться ваше приложение

И прочетайте [ето](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python) там есть моного полезной информации и [ето](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/working-with-django) )